# Why is nth child not working on my Ul element

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to select the 6th child of the Unordered list and it just can't seem to select the item. Is it because the LI's have an anchor as a child?

```css
.nav-links ul:nth-child(6) {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Vectors</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Photos</a></li>
  <li><a href="">PSD</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Video</a></li>
  <li><a href="">More <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></a></li>
  <li id="nth"><a href="">Submit</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><img src="Gmail_icon_(2020).svg.png" alt="" width="20px"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><img src="meta-logo.png" alt="" width="30px"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you mean `ul li:nth-child(6)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Updated to select the sixth *immediate `li` child*, instead of *every sixth child anywhere under the `ul`*.

Your selector is set up to select the `ul` that is the 6th child, when it appears you want the 6th `li`. Not sure what your intent is with the margin, but this will fix your selector:

```css
/* also omitted the '.nav-links' qualifier because it's not in your markup */
ul > li:nth-child(6) {
  margin-left: auto;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Vectors</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Photos</a></li>
  <li><a href="">PSD</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Video</a></li>
  <li><a href="">More <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></a></li>
  <li id="nth"><a href="">Submit</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><img src="Gmail_icon_(2020).svg.png" alt="" width="20px"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><img src="meta-logo.png" alt="" width="30px"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```